# Разница между Hardware MTU и IP MTU?

Tags: linux, c, сеть, cisco, network-manager

Встретил недавно ссылку на хабре, об HW MTU и IP MTU. Частично вроде все понятное, но целой картины я не могу увидеть.

1. Зачем нам вообще HW MTU, единственное в чем вижу смысл так это что он не будет пропускать с тегами в L2?
2. В Linux, как я понял, имплементирован только IP MTU, то есть размеры L2 Header, MPLS и разные теги отбрасываются?
3. Если, так, то есть ли какие-то возможности в создании HW MTU на Linux?

Comment: Ну и где ссылка?

Comment: HW MTU - это то, что может железо. Грубо считай, что это размер приёмного буфера в чипе внешнего интерфейса. Если он полтора килобайта, то два в него не запихать чисто физически (меньше - запросто).

Comment: @Akina не путайте с mru

Comment: @eri MTU - размер кадра передачи, MRU - размер кадра приёма. Применительно к обсуждаемой теме иной значимой разницы нет имхо. Ну если не считать того, что на каждом уровне модели они свои.

Comment: HW MTU (MAXIMUM transmission unit) как правило, задан стандартом, и выше него не прыгнуть. IP MTU от него зависит очевидным образом, т.к. пакет IP инкапсулируется во фреймы нижележащего уровня. Если, к примеру, у вас гигабитная ethernet-сеть, и на ней везде включена поддержка jumbo frames, то можно поиграться с установкой MTU около 8 кбайт.

Answer (score 1):

> HW MTU на Linux?

Этот параметр определяется **железом** а не ОС. Вот тут, достаточно подробно всё расписано:

https://habr.com/ru/post/226807/

Что-то я не могу понять, как можно "создать HW MTU" для сетевого адаптера купленного у производителя...

Comment: В этой статье написано что hw mtu определяется ОС

Comment: @eri Программно определяется, какой размер будет использоваться. А то, какое максимальное значение может иметь этот размер, определяется именно железом. Выше железного ограничения не прыгнуть, вот хоть ты там в ОС обнастраивайся. Меньше - можно.

Comment: В этой статье которую вы скинули и в тех же примерах самой циско/юбиквити есть показательные команды, которые сетят HW MTU и IP MTU,а так же MPLS MTU. Железо устанавливает максимальный предел который возможно установить.